# xaml. Treeview. How to Remove indent in child items

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

How to remove this red indent in TreeView? 

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p9Ac.png)

Comment: You are wrong. I did not find elements in ContentTemplate which do it.

ItemsPresenter Margin can help, but i think it's not good decision